# Killing a process using sh and bash

Tags: bash, process, sh, kill

I need to kill a process using the same command in both sh and bash (In a script). Normally I would do the following in bash:

```
SCRIPT=$(basename $0) #So the script knows itself
killall -9 $SCRIPT #Kill itself
```

However this does not seem to work using SH

Any suggestions on a solution that will work in either.

Is there an easier or more correct way to completely exit a script. Seems I have revisited this question many times over the years and never found the official correct way.

Comment: What process are you tying to kill? The current shell?

Comment: That should work in both `sh` and `bash`. If you are trying it on different machines, the problem is likely that `killall` (an external command, not part of either `sh` or `bash`) is not available. In any case, don't use `-9` to kill your program; that is intended only for stopping buggy programs that don't respond to any other signal. The default signal (`TERM`) should work fine; failing that, try `INT` (-2).

Comment: Why not just use `exit`, though, to end the script? Script suicide seems a little odd.

Comment: exit didnt seem to work on occasion

Comment: Ah I bet I know why. exit cant be used inside functions i believe because it just exits the function and doesnt kill the original script.

Comment: @Atomiklan If you're planning to kill the parent script you can play around with `$PPID` (may only be available to bash). Just make sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, I think exit is actually going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically to let the script kill itself, point it to `$$` which presents the process ID of the shell.

```
kill "$$"
```

Avoid SIGKILL (`9`) when not necessary. Only use it on applications that get significantly unresponsive.

The default signal sent is SIGTERM (15), and there are other signals that *could* also terminate the process which may be safer than SIGKILL. One of those are SIGQUIT, SIGABRT, and SIGHUP.

Comment: Can you redirect "Terminated" to /dev/null or something similar so it is silent?

Comment: @Atomiklan From what context are you calling this kill command?

Comment: The `Terminated` message is sent by the shell that monitors the killed process. You should run `disown` to that process to remove it from the job table before killing it.

Comment: Looks like exit is going to work, however this is a great backup solution. Thanks